# Longtable with too many columns and not centered

Tags: tables, longtable

These are my codes for longtable:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l|l|l|l|l|l}
\caption {Covid-19 Test Results by Demographics} \label{tab:title} \\
% header and footer information
    \hline
    Variable & Negative, N = 25 & Pending, N = 42 & Positive, N = 395 & (Missing), N = 91 & All, N=553\\
    \hline
    Homeless &  &  &  &  & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}No & 15 (2.7\%) & 23 (4.2\%) & 246 (44\%) & 56 (10\%) & 340 (61\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Yes & 8 (1.4\%) & 14 (2.5\%) & 78 (14\%) & 14 (2.5\%) & 114 (21\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 2 (0.4\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 71 (13\%) & 21 (3.8\%) & 99 (18\%)\\
    \hline
    Age Group &  &  &  &  & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}0-14 & 1 (0.2\%) & 6 (1.1\%) & 67 (12\%) & 12 (2.2\%) & 86 (16\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}15-19 & 0 (0\%) & 4 (0.7\%) & 28 (5.1\%) & 6 (1.1\%) & 38 (6.9\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}20-24 & 1 (0.2\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 21 (3.8\%) & 10 (1.8\%) & 37 (6.7\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}25-29 & 3 (0.5\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 22 (4.0\%) & 6 (1.1\%) & 32 (5.8\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}30-34 & 1 (0.2\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 21 (3.8\%) & 6 (1.1\%) & 29 (5.2\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}35-39 & 1 (0.2\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 37 (6.7\%) & 6 (1.1\%) & 46 (8.3\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}40-44 & 2 (0.4\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 22 (4.0\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 31 (5.6\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}45-49 & 3 (0.5\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 21 (3.8\%) & 0 (0\%) & 29 (5.2\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}50-54 & 3 (0.5\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 15 (2.7\%) & 9 (1.6\%) & 29 (5.2\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}55-59 & 0 (0\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 24 (4.3\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 30 (5.4\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}60-64 & 3 (0.5\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 24 (4.3\%) & 9 (1.6\%) & 38 (6.9\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}65-69 & 1 (0.2\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 33 (6.0\%) & 11 (2.0\%) & 46 (8.3\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}70-74 & 3 (0.5\%) & 3 (0.5\%) & 33 (6.0\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 41 (7.4\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}75+ & 3 (0.5\%) & 7 (1.3\%) & 25 (4.5\%) & 4 (0.7\%) & 39 (7.1\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 0 (0\%) & 0 (0\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 0 (0\%) & 2 (0.4\%)\\
    \hline
    Gender &  &  &  &  & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Male & 13 (2.4\%) & 18 (3.3\%) & 220 (40\%) & 53 (9.6\%) & 304 (55\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Female & 12 (2.2\%) & 23 (4.2\%) & 170 (31\%) & 37 (6.7\%) & 242 (44\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 0 (0\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 7 (1.3\%)\\
    \hline
    Race-NHOPI &  &  &  &  & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}NHOPI & 7 (1.3\%) & 12 (2.2\%) & 96 (17\%) & 24 (4.3\%) & 139 (25\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 18 (3.3\%) & 30 (5.4\%) & 299 (54\%) & 67 (12\%) & 414 (75\%)\\
    \hline
    Race-American Indian &  &  &  &  & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}American Indian & 0 (0\%) & 0 (0\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 6 (1.1\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 25 (4.5\%) & 42 (7.6\%) & 390 (71\%) & 90 (16\%) & 547 (99\%)\\
    \hline
    Race-Asian &  &  &  &  & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Asian & 4 (0.7\%) & 8 (1.4\%) & 78 (14\%) & 21 (3.8\%) & 111 (20\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 21 (3.8\%) & 34 (6.1\%) & 317 (57\%) & 70 (13\%) & 442 (80\%)\\
    \hline
    Race-Black &  &  &  &  & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Black & 0 (0\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 4 (0.7\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 25 (4.5\%) & 41 (7.4\%) & 393 (71\%) & 90 (16\%) & 549 (99\%)\\
    \hline
    Race-Hispanic &  &  &  &  & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Hispanic & 0 (0\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 13 (2.4\%) & 4 (0.7\%) & 18 (3.3\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 25 (4.5\%) & 41 (7.4\%) & 382 (69\%) & 87 (16\%) & 535 (97\%)\\
    \hline
    Race-White &  &  &  &  & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}White & 0 (0\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 31 (5.6\%) & 11 (2.0\%) & 44 (8.0\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 25 (4.5\%) & 40 (7.2\%) & 364 (66\%) & 80 (14\%) & 509 (92\%)\\
    \hline
    Race-Other Race&  &  &  &  & \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Other & 2 (0.4\%) & 4 (0.7\%) & 47 (8.5\%) & 12 (2.2\%) & 65 (12\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 23 (4.2\%) & 38 (6.9\%) & 348 (63\%) & 79 (14\%) & 488 (88\%)\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}\textsuperscript{1} Statistics presented: n (\%)}\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I am trying to get the table centered and all the columns but so far getting this table as the output [image]

Any suggestions how have the longtable centered and have all the columns?

Comment: use two lines for your headings so they are not so much wider than the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use introduce linebreaks in the column heads with the `makecell`apckage and reduce the value of `\tabcolsep`, in order to reduce the table width. I took the opportunity to add some æsthetic improvements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\centering
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\caption {Covid-19 Test Results by Demographics} \label{tab:title} \\
% header and footer information
    \hline
    Variable & \thead{Negative,\\ N = 25} & \thead{Pending,\\ N = 42} & \thead{Positive,\\ N = 395} & \thead{(Missing),\\ N = 91} & \thead{All,\\ N=553}\\
\endfirsthead
\caption*{Covid-19 Test Results by Demographics\enspace (continued)} \\
    \hline
    Variable & \thead{Negative,\\ N = 25} & \thead{Pending,\\ N = 42} & \thead{Positive,\\ N = 395} & \thead{(Missing),\\ N = 91} & \thead{All,\\ N=553}\\
\endhead
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Homeless} \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}No & 15 (2.7\%) & 23 (4.2\%) & 246 (44\%) & 56 (10\%) & 340 (61\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Yes & 8 (1.4\%) & 14 (2.5\%) & 78 (14\%) & 14 (2.5\%) & 114 (21\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 2 (0.4\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 71 (13\%) & 21 (3.8\%) & 99 (18\%)\\
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Age Group} \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}0-14 & 1 (0.2\%) & 6 (1.1\%) & 67 (12\%) & 12 (2.2\%) & 86 (16\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}15-19 & 0 (0\%) & 4 (0.7\%) & 28 (5.1\%) & 6 (1.1\%) & 38 (6.9\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}20-24 & 1 (0.2\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 21 (3.8\%) & 10 (1.8\%) & 37 (6.7\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}25-29 & 3 (0.5\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 22 (4.0\%) & 6 (1.1\%) & 32 (5.8\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}30-34 & 1 (0.2\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 21 (3.8\%) & 6 (1.1\%) & 29 (5.2\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}35-39 & 1 (0.2\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 37 (6.7\%) & 6 (1.1\%) & 46 (8.3\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}40-44 & 2 (0.4\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 22 (4.0\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 31 (5.6\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}45-49 & 3 (0.5\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 21 (3.8\%) & 0 (0\%) & 29 (5.2\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}50-54 & 3 (0.5\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 15 (2.7\%) & 9 (1.6\%) & 29 (5.2\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}55-59 & 0 (0\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 24 (4.3\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 30 (5.4\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}60-64 & 3 (0.5\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 24 (4.3\%) & 9 (1.6\%) & 38 (6.9\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}65-69 & 1 (0.2\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 33 (6.0\%) & 11 (2.0\%) & 46 (8.3\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}70-74 & 3 (0.5\%) & 3 (0.5\%) & 33 (6.0\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 41 (7.4\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}75+ & 3 (0.5\%) & 7 (1.3\%) & 25 (4.5\%) & 4 (0.7\%) & 39 (7.1\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 0 (0\%) & 0 (0\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 0 (0\%) & 2 (0.4\%)\\
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Gender} \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Male & 13 (2.4\%) & 18 (3.3\%) & 220 (40\%) & 53 (9.6\%) & 304 (55\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Female & 12 (2.2\%) & 23 (4.2\%) & 170 (31\%) & 37 (6.7\%) & 242 (44\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 0 (0\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 7 (1.3\%)\\
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Race-NHOPI} \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}NHOPI & 7 (1.3\%) & 12 (2.2\%) & 96 (17\%) & 24 (4.3\%) & 139 (25\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 18 (3.3\%) & 30 (5.4\%) & 299 (54\%) & 67 (12\%) & 414 (75\%)\\
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Race-American Indian} \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}American Indian & 0 (0\%) & 0 (0\%) & 5 (0.9\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 6 (1.1\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 25 (4.5\%) & 42 (7.6\%) & 390 (71\%) & 90 (16\%) & 547 (99\%)\\
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Race-Asian} \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Asian & 4 (0.7\%) & 8 (1.4\%) & 78 (14\%) & 21 (3.8\%) & 111 (20\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 21 (3.8\%) & 34 (6.1\%) & 317 (57\%) & 70 (13\%) & 442 (80\%)\\
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Race-Black} \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Black & 0 (0\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 4 (0.7\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 25 (4.5\%) & 41 (7.4\%) & 393 (71\%) & 90 (16\%) & 549 (99\%)\\
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Race-Hispanic} \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Hispanic & 0 (0\%) & 1 (0.2\%) & 13 (2.4\%) & 4 (0.7\%) & 18 (3.3\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 25 (4.5\%) & 41 (7.4\%) & 382 (69\%) & 87 (16\%) & 535 (97\%)\\
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Race-White} \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}White & 0 (0\%) & 2 (0.4\%) & 31 (5.6\%) & 11 (2.0\%) & 44 (8.0\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 25 (4.5\%) & 40 (7.2\%) & 364 (66\%) & 80 (14\%) & 509 (92\%)\\
    \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{Race-Other Race} \\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}Other & 2 (0.4\%) & 4 (0.7\%) & 47 (8.5\%) & 12 (2.2\%) & 65 (12\%)\\
    \hline
    \hspace{0.3em}(Missing) & 23 (4.2\%) & 38 (6.9\%) & 348 (63\%) & 79 (14\%) & 488 (88\%)\\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}\textsuperscript{1} Statistics presented: n (\%)}\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wow looks great! I was using landscape as well

Answer (score 1):

Probably you also like this alternative layout based on `tabular*`, `booktabs` and `siunitx`. If you reduce the font size to `\small`, the whole table fits into the textblock of a standart `article`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=\,--\,}

\renewcommand{\defaultaddspace}{3pt}

\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\centering 
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\caption {Covid-19 Test Results by Demographics} \label{tab:title}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\hspace{6pt}}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                S[table-format=2]
                S[table-format=1.1,input-symbols = {()},table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post=\%),table-align-text-post=false]@{\;}
                S[table-format=2]
                S[table-format=1.1,input-symbols = {()},table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post=\%),table-align-text-post=false]@{\;}
                S[table-format=3]
                S[table-format=2.1,input-symbols = {()},table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post=\%),table-align-text-post=false]@{\;}
                S[table-format=2]
                S[table-format=2.1,input-symbols = {()},table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post=\%),table-align-text-post=false]@{\;}
                S[table-format=3]
                S[table-format=2.1,input-symbols = {()},table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post=\%),table-align-text-post=false]@{}
                }
  \toprule
    Variable 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Negative,\\ N = 25}} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Pending,\\ N = 42}} 
          & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Positive,\\ N = 395}} 
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{(Missing),\\ N = 91}} 
              & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{All,\\ N = 553}}\\ 
  \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\itshape Homeless} \\
    No                & 15 & (2.7\%) & 23 & (4.2\%) & 246 & (44\%) & 56 & (10\%)  & 340 & (61\%)\\
    Yes               & 8  & (1.4\%) & 14 & (2.5\%) & 78  & (14\%) & 14 & (2.5\%) & 114 & (21\%)\\
    (Missing)         & 2  & (0.4\%) & 5  & (0.9\%) & 71  & (13\%) & 21 & (3.8\%) & 99  & (18\%)\\
  \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\itshape Age Group} \\    
    \numrange{0}{14}  & 1  & (0.2\%) & 6 & (1.1\%) & 67   & (12\%)  & 12 & (2.2\%) & 86 & (16\%)\\    
    \numrange{15}{19} & 0  & (0\%)   & 4 & (0.7\%) & 28   & (5.1\%) & 6 & (1.1\%)  & 38 & (6.9\%)\\    
    \numrange{20}{24} & 1  & (0.2\%) & 5 & (0.9\%) & 21   & (3.8\%) & 10 & (1.8\%) & 37 & (6.7\%)\\ 
  \addlinespace   
    \numrange{25}{29} & 3  & (0.5\%) & 1 & (0.2\%) & 22   & (4.0\%) & 6  & (1.1\%) & 32 & (5.8\%)\\    
    \numrange{30}{34} & 1  & (0.2\%) & 1 & (0.2\%) & 21   & (3.8\%) & 6  & (1.1\%) & 29 & (5.2\%)\\    
    \numrange{35}{39} & 1  & (0.2\%) & 2 & (0.4\%) & 37   & (6.7\%) & 6  & (1.1\%) & 46 & (8.3\%)\\
  \addlinespace     
    \numrange{40}{44} & 2  & (0.4\%) & 2 & (0.4\%) & 22   & (4.0\%) & 5  & (0.9\%) & 31 & (5.6\%)\\    
    \numrange{45}{49} & 3  & (0.5\%) & 5 & (0.9\%) & 21   & (3.8\%) & 0  & (0\%)   & 29 & (5.2\%)\\    
    \numrange{50}{54} & 3  & (0.5\%) & 2 & (0.4\%) & 15   & (2.7\%) & 9  & (1.6\%) & 29 & (5.2\%)\\  
  \addlinespace   
    \numrange{55}{59} & 0  & (0\%)   & 1 & (0.2\%) & 24   & (4.3\%) & 5  & (0.9\%) & 30 & (5.4\%)\\    
    \numrange{60}{64} & 3  & (0.5\%) & 2 & (0.4\%) & 24   & (4.3\%) & 9  & (1.6\%) & 38 & (6.9\%)\\    
    \numrange{65}{69} & 1  & (0.2\%) & 1 & (0.2\%) & 33   & (6.0\%) & 11 & (2.0\%) & 46 & (8.3\%)\\ 
  \addlinespace    
    \numrange{70}{74} & 3  & (0.5\%) & 3 & (0.5\%) & 33   & (6.0\%) & 2  & (0.4\%) & 41 & (7.4\%)\\   
    75+               & 3  & (0.5\%) & 7 & (1.3\%) & 25   & (4.5\%) & 4  & (0.7\%) & 39 & (7.1\%)\\    
    (Missing)         & 0  & (0\%)   & 0 & (0\%)   & 2    & (0.4\%) & 0  & (0\%)   & 2  & (0.4\%)\\
  \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\itshape Gender} \\ 
    Male              & 13 & (2.4\%) & 18 & (3.3\%) & 220 & (40\%)  & 53 & (9.6\%) & 304 & (55\%)\\
    Female            & 12 & (2.2\%) & 23 & (4.2\%) & 170 & (31\%)  & 37 & (6.7\%) & 242 & (44\%)\\
    (Missing)         & 0  & (0\%)   & 1  & (0.2\%) & 5   & (0.9\%) & 1  & (0.2\%) & 7   & (1.3\%)\\
  \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l}{\itshape Race} \\
    NHOPI             & 7  & (1.3\%) & 12 & (2.2\%) & 96  & (17\%)  & 24 & (4.3\%) & 139 &  (25\%)\\
    (Missing)         & 18 & (3.3\%) & 30 & (5.4\%) & 299 & (54\%)  & 67 &  (12\%) & 414 & (75\%)\\
  \addlinespace
    American Indian   & 0  & (0\%)   & 0  & (0\%)   & 5   & (0.9\%) & 1  & (0.2\%) & 6   & (1.1\%)\\
    (Missing)         & 25 & (4.5\%) & 42 & (7.6\%) & 390 & (71\%)  & 90 & (16\%)  & 547 & (99\%)\\
  \addlinespace
    Asian             & 4  & (0.7\%) & 8  & (1.4\%) & 78  & (14\%)  & 21 & (3.8\%) & 111 & (20\%)\\
    (Missing)         & 21 & (3.8\%) & 34 & (6.1\%) & 317 & (57\%)  & 70 & (13\%)  & 442 & (80\%)\\
  \addlinespace
    Black             & 0  & (0\%)   & 1  & (0.2\%) & 2   & (0.4\%) & 1  & (0.2\%) & 4   & (0.7\%)\\
    (Missing)         & 25 & (4.5\%) & 41 & (7.4\%) & 393 & (71\%)  & 90 & (16\%)  & 549 & (99\%)\\
  \addlinespace
    Hispanic          & 0  & (0\%)   & 1  & (0.2\%) & 13  & (2.4\%) & 4  & (0.7\%) & 18  & (3.3\%)\\
    (Missing)         & 25 & (4.5\%) & 41 & (7.4\%) & 382 & (69\%)  & 87 & (16\%)  & 535 & (97\%)\\
  \addlinespace
    White             & 0  & (0\%)   & 2  & (0.4\%) & 31  & (5.6\%) & 11 & (2.0\%) & 44  & (8.0\%)\\
    (Missing)         & 25 & (4.5\%) & 40 & (7.2\%) & 364 & (66\%)  & 80 & (14\%)  & 509 & (92\%)\\
  \addlinespace
    Other             & 2  & (0.4\%) & 4  & (0.7\%) & 47  & (8.5\%) & 12 & (2.2\%) & 65  & (12\%)\\
    (Missing)         & 23 & (4.2\%) & 38 & (6.9\%) & 348 & (63\%)  & 79 & (14\%)  & 488 & (88\%)\\
  \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{6}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}\textsuperscript{1} Statistics presented: n (\%)}\\
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @leandrilis Looks very nice! Thanks for your answer as well.